# Save a list of several Numpy arrays that represent images, on the disk

Tags: image, numpy

I have a list that contains numerous Numpy arrays. Each represents an image.
How can I save them all as images?
Thank you,
Ziv

Comment: *How can I save them all as images?*  please elaborate on it. Do you mean as a specific file type? or simply store data in a single file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest in my opinion is `np.save(saving_file_path, array_to_save)`, see documentation here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html.
You load it with `np.load(file_path_to_load)`.
You can just iterate through your list:

```
for i, img in enumerate(imgs):
    np.save(f'image_num_{i}', img)
```

The files here are of type .npy. This file type is good for saving results and loading them for later use in another code.

If you want to save it as an image, a different function should be used. Instead of np.save, try:

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
`plt.imsave(file_name, arr)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but now the output of your suggestion:

for i, img in enumerate(train_images):
    np.save('train'+str(i+1)+'.'+image_format,loaded_images[i])

is 'train#.PNG.npy' rather than a PNG file.

Do you have any idea on how to solve this??

Comment: I'll edit my question with another suggestion.